# starting countdown timer on right mouse click in javascript

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer, onmouseclick

I have here code, in JavaScript which presents simple countdown timer

```
var Timer;
var TotalSec;

function CreateTimer(Timer ID, Time){
    Timer = document.getElementByID(Timer ID);
    TotalSec = Time;
    UpdateTimer() window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function Tick() { 
    if (TotalSeconds <= 0) { 
        alert(message)
         return; 
        }
 TotalSeconds -= 1; 
 UpdateTimer() window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000); 
}

function UpdateTimer() {
 Timer.innerHTML = TotalSeconds;
}
```

and I also have code which is showing a msg when right click is activated

```
var message="Right click? You are using it wrong!  Thank you for your understanding.";

function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

Ok, now, what I want to do is, when somebody makes right click on website, it triggers my 5  sec timer and shows msg: "Your bla bla bla bla will end in +(how many seconds)", and when counter reaches 0, it is supposed to set msg:"Nah I`m just kidding bla bla bla..."

Can anybody help me please? Basically, I have everything, just don't know how to connect all things. 
I'm creating something for a friend of mine for one blog on blogger.com and would like to see it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've changed my code a little bit, but now I'm getting: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property `innerHTML` of null

```
<script language='JavaScript'>

function disableIE() {if (document.all) {countDown();return false;}
}
function disableNS(e) {
if (document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {countDown();return false;}
}
}
if (document.layers) {
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=disableNS;
} else {
document.onmouseup=disableNS;document.oncontextmenu=disableIE;
}
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("countDown();return false");


//////


var count =3; 


function countDown(){  
 if (count <=0){  
    kreirajProzor();
  popuniprozor("Your computer will shut down in "+count+" seconds.");    
 }else{  
  count--;  
  document.getElementById("prozor").innerHTML = "Your computer will shut down in "+count+" seconds.";  
  setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);  
 }  
}  



//////

var kreirano = false;

function kreirajProzor(){
    if (!kreirano)return;

    kreirano = true;

    var html = "";

    html+='<div id="prozor"></div>';
    html+='<style type="text/css">';
    html+='#prozor{position:absolute;border:1px solid black; width:500px; height:250px; background:white;left:30%; top:200px;}';
    html+='</style>';
    document.write(html);

}


function popuniprozor(text){

    document.getElementById("prozor").innerHTML = text;

}
</script>
```

How can I solve this one?